Adding a 1x1 contact to a folder
As far as I remember, I've always been able to add a 1x1 Contact to a folder: simply create a 1x1 Contacts Widget and then move it to a folder.
I still have some here, and are just working:

However it seems like I don't have that option anymore:

Online sources are completely useless, as they are either too old, or they don't take into account the "putting it into a folder" step (they suggest to add the big widget and then resize it, but it doesn't go into folders).

I have still the option to create a 1x1 contact link widget on my both devices (one Google Pixel with Google Contact app and one Samsung with Samsung contact app)

It is possible to add an app shortcut to a home screen folder, but not an app widget.
App shortcuts is a 1x1 icon with a small app icon in the bottom-right corner. App widgets vary in size and may have a 1x1 size, but it does not show the app icon in the bottom-right corner.
Google Contacts has 2 widgets and 3 shortcuts:

Individual contact (widget, 2x2)
Favorite contacts (widget, 4x1)
Contact (shortcut, 1x1)
Direct dial (shortcut, 1x1)
Direct message (shortcut, 1x1)

Some launchers may combine shortcuts and widgets in the same place, like Google Pixel's stock launcher and Samsung One UI's stock launcher. How to add app shortcuts may vary depending on the devices.
